# Which fake meats are healthy?

Tags: health, food, substitutes, nutrition, meat-substitutes

I've heard that not all foods veg*n foods styled to resemble meat are healthy; some are quite processed, high in sodium, etc.  What are the main health concerns when eating fake meat? How can I identify healthier meat substitutes?

Comment: It might be better to call them meat 'replacements', since "fake meat" could mean something attempting to pose as meat.

Comment: This depends so much on what kind of fake meat. Seitan? Tofu? Lupin?

Comment: I agree with SuperBiasedMan, since the term fake meat is rather ambiguous. To add to Turion's question, I have heard dried soy cubes called fake meat, as well as Quorn products and even processed wheat that is supposed to taste like meat etc. It might be a good idea to explain a little what kind of "fake meat" you mean.

Comment: Just because something is processed it doesn't mean it's per se unhealthy. It depends so much on the exact type of processing, on the ingredients used and so on.

Comment: I think this is too broad. There are a lot of factors that can go into "healthy", and that varies from person-to-person. There are a lot of "meat substitutes", ranging from attempting to imitate to just an alternative protein source. _That all being said_, I think that it could be a great question if narrowed down, since understanding the pitfalls of pretend meats (e.g. "chicken" nuggets, veggie "burgers") is a valuable resource.

Answer (score -2):

The only way to really know if food is healthy is to cook it yourself. Meat substitutes such as pre-made vegetarian "burgers" or "sausages" in particular are high in preservatives and sodium. They're also very costly compared to other vegetarian options.

I'd recommend trying to cook vegetarian dishes that are not trying to "replace" meat such as lentil curries, Tex/Mex with beans, or Asian stir fries (with Tofu). If you're trying to avoid meat, substituting is rather strange and may actually make it harder to adapt to vegetarianism. Many long-term vegetarians don't remember what they're missing and even find meat (or substitutes) unappealing.

If emulating meat dishes is your thing, I'd recommend trying the recipes of [Lukas Volger](http://www.madebylukas.com/recipes/). I found his cookbook really good and it looks like they've released pre-mix products on the web (although likely only for sale in the US). They're more about preparing burgers and like that have the same style as meat dishes, rather than emulating the flavours.

Comment: Using fresh foods such as vegetables would have less preservatives than most pre-made foods. Preparing it yourself, you'd also be able to control how much seasoning (such as salt) are added. This is in particular would address the OP's concerns about Sodium. I've suggested home-cooking over eating out because there is limited vegetarian options where I live, they tend to cost more than home-cooking, and restaurants tend to be very liberal with salts, sugars, and fats/oils. If you're looking to substitute meat long-term cooking from scratch is the way to go.

Comment: While I agree with a lot of what you're writing, I find that your answer sidesteps the question. You're basically saying "Just avoid them. Oh, and here are some great recipes." That's all great advice, but you're not answering the question which fake meats are healthy and which aren't.

Comment: Plus, I've been recently diagnosed with IBS so I can't eat whole soy beans, wheat, lactose, or fructose either so processed foods aren't really an options for me any more. Honestly, I don't really miss them much. They're overpriced junk IMHO.

Comment: Does "none of them are" not count as an answer? I figure "here's some alternatives" is better than rejecting the question outright.

Comment: @TomKelly, it counts, but then you need to add some explanations at the very least, and ideally some scientific sources.

Comment: Very sorry to hear that you can't eat soy beans and wheat. But I have to wonder then whether the answer is only fit for other people suffering from IBS as well? After all, there are many people who can eat soy without problems, and they would like to know how healthy tofu is for them.

Comment: @Turion It's fairly common knowledge that processed foods contain sodium and preservatives. If the OP were to give some specific products I could address their concerns with them. I've refrained from giving examples of products since they're likely specific to my region (which is not the USA as seems to be common here).

Comment: I am going to delete my original comment as I misunderstood, you meant prepare the "substitute" yourself like I make "chorizo" from bean paste and sundried tomatoes etc. In general "it can't be done" IS an answer, but I think you are focussing on a particular type of product here - what about plain tofu and tempeh? They are traditional foods, simply processed, often with very few additives...

Comment: @Turion Sure, hence I've recommended the Volger recipes/products and based my answer mainly on experiences as vegetarian before my diagnosis.

Comment: Agree that the OP should be more specific on the product. Disagree that in general, processed foods contain sodium and preservatives. Organic, unflavoured tofu usually doesn't contain either.

Comment: Possibly the issues with this answer are pointing to the fact that the question is too broad as I feared when I first saw it :/ I hope it can be salvaged. I think this answer is somewhat missing the point (although I reiterate that "don't do it" is in general a valid answer), since the OP themselves pointed out that some meat substitutes are highly processed and that means they are unhealthy in OP's view. This answer essentially says "processed meat substitutes are unhealthy so don't eat them, just eat something else." I think we need to edit the question to get clarity :(

Comment: @Turion Possibly but I do not support or recommend the Organics industry. There is no health benefit and they may still use (unregulated) pesticides. I've also cited cost as a reason for self-catering and organic products tend to be more expensive. I do not think many processed burger/sausage products are healthy (at least those available here). I do not regard Tofu as processed or unhealthy, in fact I've _recommended it_ already, and regularly cook Asian dishes as my partner is Japanese.

Comment: I find that you're making very subjective claims here. You do not regard Tofu as processed? What's your objective definition of "processed" then? Also, this question is asking for _facts_, and not recommendations.

Comment: @Zanna Sorry but I'd prefer if this weren't edited to alter the meaning. The OP has genuine concerns and I disagree that (highly processed) pre-made/cooked meat substitutes are necessary at all. If anyone has any better suggestions, they're welcome to post another answer.

Comment: I'm taking a break from this conversation as I'm finding it too tense. I will be back.

Comment: Equally here. It seems like we're all getting a bit emotional on this thing. Let's calm down for a few hours and see whether OP can improve the question, and then we can have another look.